# Not able to reach 60fps in opencv with a supported camera

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, webcam, frame-rate

For my project i need to process frames at high rate, the more the better but at least 60fps are mandatory. Im using opencv 4.1.1 in a Windows 10 machine vía Anaconda in case you need to know the platform. With the code provided im able to get 30 fps whatever is the frame rate or resolution setted.

My camera model is an ELP-USBFHD01M-L21, which is capable of:

1. 1920 (H) x 1080 (V) MJPEG 30fps YUY2 6fps
2. 1280 (H) x 1024 (V) MJPEG 30fps YUY2 6fps
3. 1280 (H) x 720 (V) MJPEG 60fps YUY2 9fps
4. 1024 (H) x 768 (V) MJPEG 30fps YUY2 9fps
5. 800 (H) x 600 (V) MJPEG 60fps YUY2 21fps
6. 640 (H) x 480 (V) MJPEG 120fps YUY2 30fps
7. 352(H) x 288 (V) MJPEG 120fps YUY2 30fps
8. 320 (H) x 240 (V) MJPEG 120fps YUY2 30fps

All of those frame rates are correctly tested with AMCAP software.

How can i reach the desired frame rate?

Code:

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

    VIDEO_SOURCE = 0
    CAMERA_CAPTURE_FPS = 60
    CAMERA_CAPTURE_WIDTH = 1280
    CAMERA_CAPTURE_HEIGHT = 720

    frameCounter = 0
    fps = 0
    startTime = time.time()

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_SOURCE)

    print("Parameters BEFORE assignment: ")
    print("WIDTH: " + str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)))
    print("HEIGHT: " + str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
    print("FPS: " + str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)))
    print("FOURCC: " + str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC)))

    # Noting seems to change adding or deleting this 2 lines
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G')
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc)
    
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, CAMERA_CAPTURE_WIDTH)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, CAMERA_CAPTURE_HEIGHT)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, CAMERA_CAPTURE_FPS)

    print()
    print("Parameters AFTER assignment: ")
    print("WIDTH: " + str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)))
    print("HEIGHT: " + str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
    print("FPS: " + str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)))
    print("FOURCC: " + str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC)))


    while True:

        ret, frame = cap.read()

        cv2.putText(frame, "FPS: " + str(fps), (20, 40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        frameCounter += 1

        if time.time() - startTime >= 1:
            fps = frameCounter
            frameCounter = 0
            startTime = time.time()

        cv2.imshow("Camera stream", frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()
```

Comment: Try setting the width and the height **before** setting the frame rate. I think, if the default size is 1920x1080 and you try to set the frame rate to 60 fps it will be rejected because it can't do that rate at that size, so set the smaller size first and then try for the higher rate.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the reply, i've setted before, after and even not setting any resolution, the results are always the same. I also tried setting up all the parameters with VideoCapture() default constructor and opening the stream after, nothing changed.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried getting all the settings after setting them to see if they have *"stuck"*?

Comment: Done just now, the info im getting is:

Parameters BEFORE assignment:
WIDTH: 640.0
HEIGHT: 480.0
FPS: 120.10136555252633
FOURCC: 842094158.0

so in this case i comment the all the SET just to show the original camera stream with the default parameters and the 30 fps keep apearing

Comment: Ok, try not drawing text on your frame, and not measuring the frame rate and not displaying the image. So, read the start time once, followed just a simple loop that reads 1,000 frames without doing anything else at all and then get the time at the end.

Comment: Thanks for keep repliying @MarkSetchell, i've tried to quit all the process that you said just leaving the cap.read() and the waitkey() functions for minimal deployment and even setting or not the parameters the result is always the same, 10 sec aproximately for reading 300 fps, as expected 30fps.

Comment: The key here is that setting fourcc does not work. You are now using NV12 which is the native format of the camera and it is not so efficient. Two chances: try to move around the line that set FOURCC to MJPG (like after the line that set fps), or try changing fourcc to 'M','P','4','V'

Comment: You can also check the return value of cap.set on FPS to see if the backend is accepting the setting. Related to this, you can also try changing the used backend passing the proper argument to the constructor of VideoCapture.

Comment: @Doch88 Already done all the changes you said with 3 diferent backends, CV_MSMF ,CV_DSHOW and the default constructor CV_ANY. In all 3 situations the fourcc code is never setted, i will try the same setup in ubuntu just in case for discarding possible OS issues as i found here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7013

Comment: Yeah, it is probably a OS issue, but we can try to bypass it. Have you installed OpenCV via pip or have you built it from sources? If  you used pip you can try building OpenCV from sources. The pip wheel is a bit buggy sometimes. You can also try to build OpenCV using the CMake option that specify to build third party libraries. Doing so, we can avoid issues deriving from backends library versions.

Comment: Are you observing the frame rate via Remote Desktop or on a physical machine? The next step would be to profile your whole application.

Comment: Well finally the issue was some kind of backend compatibility with Windows because in  Ubuntu i have been able to execute my script without any problems, not even changed the video backend used in Windows and the codec, which works both well with MP4V and MPEG, thank for all the support!